# How do I enchant my sword?

Tags: candy-box

I have the chocolate sword now, but buttons in the forge is disabled..

Why? I have too many candies and lollipops...

Answer (score 1):

You must have a Minor Health Potion, a Fire Scroll, or an Imp Scroll in order to enchant your sword in the forge. You also must have used lollipops and candy to enhance your sword, I believe.

Comment: And a chocolate bar, which you can get from the Swampy Swamp Frog.

Comment: @fredley I thought that's how he got the chocolate sword.

Comment: SaintWacko is correct, that's how you create the Chocolate Sword.

However, Saint's answer isn't correct. You must first sharpen your Chocolate Sword via the Forge to create a Sharp Chocolate Sword. You cannot enchant a regular Chocolate Sword.

Comment: @Murkantilism Ah, alright. It's been a while since I've played it.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created a chocolate sword and acquired the map to the Forge, you can **sharpen** the sword to created a Sharp Chocolate Sword.

Once you have a sharp Chocolate Sword, you can enchant it via the Forge if you have the required item (Minor Health Potion, a Fire Scroll, or an Imp Scroll).

Check out [the Candy Box wiki](http://www.candyboxwiki.com/wiki/Swords), it's very detailed and straight forward.